# Need to list the items by hiding method

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a heading to list the items
List Name
List 1
List 2
List 3
List 4

but i need to display the listed items after click the "List Name". The Listed Items are to be hidden until click the "List Name". What is the coding for it in HTML

Need Coding for HTML

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it's works for me :

```js
  document.getElementById("list-name").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var listItems = document.getElementById("list-items");
    if (listItems.style.display === "none") {
      listItems.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      listItems.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
```

```html
<button id="list-name">List Name</button>
<ul id="list-items" style="display:none;">
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
  <li>List 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery or javascript for this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".list-name").click(function(){
    $(".list").toggle();
  });
});
</script>

<ul class="list">
   <li>A</li>
   <li>B</li>
   <li>C</li>
   <li>D</li>
</ul>

<a href="" class="list-name">List Name</a>
```

You can use this script to hide and show the list item on click.